# Proof the root of a distance a distance

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

i need to prove that $
\delta(x, y) = d(x, y)^c$, $c\in [0, 1]$ 
is a distance (we know $d(x, y)$ is a distance) . Only the triangle inequality is not trivial. I have been given an indication that I don't quite understand: compare the function $t \mapsto t^c$ with the identity. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: For **every** $c$?!

Comment: I forgot that c is between 0 and 1

Comment: Then please edit your question.

Comment: You should keep in mind what definition of $0^0$ you're using when claiming it's a distance for $c=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b\geqslant0$, then$$a+b\leqslant(a^c+b^c)^{1/c},\tag1$$since the map $t\mapsto t^c$ is concave. So\begin{align}\delta(x,z)&=d(x,z)^c\\&\leqslant\bigl(d(x,y)+d(y,z)\bigr)^c\\&\leqslant d(x,y)^c+d(y,z)^c\text{ (by (1))}\\&=\delta(x,y)+\delta(y,z).\end{align}